# Access Denied in spite of having admin role

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, roles

I have this configuration class:

```
package com.practice.springbootdemo.config;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class MyConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{

    @Autowired
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder builder) throws Exception {
        builder.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("myname").password("abcd")
                .roles("ADMIN");
    }


    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/home")
                .hasRole("ADMIN")
                .and()
                .formLogin();
    }
}
```

However, when I query "/home" and provide the credntials:

```
username: myname
password: abcd
```

it gives me Access Denied.

I cannot understand why. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the issue on my own.

Apparently, there was an issue with Spring's Passsword Encoder.
I had to explicitly cancel the default encoding operation in Spring by adding `{noop}` before the password, like so:

```
builder.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("myname").password("{noop}abcd")
            .roles("ADMIN");
```

In this way the password was, in plain-text `"abcd"` (without quotes).
Thus this matched when I entered my credentials and everything works fine.